# How to use menuIsOpen prop of Select component from react-select dependency to display a button conditionally?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I am using Select component in my project for dropdowns. I need to display a button only when the dropdown list is open. But I am not able to figure out how will I use the MenuIsOpen prop to toggle the button rendering. Anyone who has worked on this or can guide me here?

Here is my custom dropdown:

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import ReactSelect from "../../../../components/ReactSelect/ReactSelect";

const NewDropdown=props=>{
    const { state, component, onChange, selectWithoutBox} = props;
    const {optionList}=component;
    const [
        btnClick,
        setbtnClick
    ]=useState(false);
    
    const [
        inputValue,
        setInputValue
    ]=useState("");
    const [
        newList,
        setNewList
    ]=useState(optionList);

    const handleBtnClick=()=>{
        setbtnClick(true);
    };
    const handleInputChange=event=>{
        setInputValue(event.target.value);
    };

    const handleKeyPress=event=>{
        if(event.key==="Enter"){
            setNewList([
                ...newList,
                {label: inputValue, value: inputValue}
            ]);
            setbtnClick(false);
            setInputValue("");
        }
    };
    component.optionList=newList;

    
    return(
        <>
            <ReactSelect component={component} state={state} onChange={onChange} 
                
                selectWithoutBox={selectWithoutBox} />
            <div >
                { !btnClick && <button className="btn btn-icon" onClick={handleBtnClick}>ADD TYPE</button>}
                { btnClick && <input className="clr-input" type="text" placeholder="Enter Type" onChange={handleInputChange} value={inputValue} 
                    onKeyPress={handleKeyPress} autoFocus
                />}
            </div>
        </>
    );

};

export default NewDropdown;
```

Here is my ReactSelect component-

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import Select from "react-select";
import { get, isEmpty } from "../../helpers";
import BasicLabel from "../BasicLabel";
import "./ReactSelect.css";
import CheckboxOption from "./CheckboxOption/index";
import ShowOtherCountLimitContainer from "./ShowOtherCountLimitContainer";
import cn from "classnames";

const ReactSelect = props => {
    const customStyles = {
        option: provided => ({
            ...provided,
            container: "black",
            wordBreak: "break-all",
            input: "black",
            option: "black",
            color: "#565656",
            zIndex: 100000
        }),
        indicatorSeparator: styles => ({
            ...styles,
            "background-color" : "#FFFFFF"
        }),
        control: (styles, state) => ({
            ...styles,
            padding: 0,
            background: "#ffffff",
            border: ".05rem solid",
            "border-color": "#ccc",
            "border-radius": ".15rem",
            "min-height": "2rem",
            "min-width": "6rem",
            "background-color": state.isDisabled ? "#f2f2f2" : "#ffffff"
        }),
        menuPortal: styles => ({
            ...styles,
            zIndex: "9999"
        }),
        menu: styles => ({
            ...styles,
            marginTop:0
        }),
        container: styles => ({
            ...styles
        })
    };
    const customTheme = theme => ({
        ...theme,
        colors: {
            ...theme.colors,
            primary25:   "#D9E4EA",
            primary:   "#D9E4EA"
        }
    });
    const { state, component, onChange, disabled = false, selectWithoutBox, menuIsOpen} = props;
    let showError = false;
    const {
        name,
        required,
        label,
        helpTextPosition,
        helpText,
        placeholder,
        optionConfig = false,
        optionList = [],
        className,
        isMulti,
        maxItems = null,
        clearable = false,
        menuPlacement = "auto",
        maxMenuHeight = 300,
        dropdownCheckbox = false,
        showOtherCountLimit = -1
    } = component;

    const options = !!optionConfig ? get(state, `${optionConfig}`, []) : optionList;

    const getSelectValue = () => {
        const selectedList = get(state, `${name}`, []);
        if (isEmpty(selectedList) || isEmpty(options)) {
            return [];
        }
        const selectedSet = new Set(selectedList);
        return options.filter(item => selectedSet.has(item.value));
    };

    const handleOnChange = selectedOption => {
        onChange({ value: selectedOption, component });
    };

    if(isMulti && maxItems && getSelectValue().length > maxItems) {
        showError = true;
    }

    const selectStyleWithoutBox = {
        control: styles => ({
            ...styles,
            borderStyle:"none",
            borderBottomStyle:"solid",
            borderRadius:"0",
            boxShadow: "none"
        })
    };
    const styles = selectWithoutBox ? {...customStyles, ...selectStyleWithoutBox} : customStyles;

    const defaultSelectProps = {
        value: getSelectValue(),
        name: "category",
        className: "multiSelectTechspecs single-select",
        onChange: handleOnChange,
        isMulti,
        options,
        styles,
        theme: customTheme,
        menuPosition: "absolute",
        isDisabled: disabled,
        placeholder,
        isClearable: clearable,
        menuPlacement,
        maxMenuHeight,
        showOtherCountLimit, 
        menuIsOpen
    };

    /* ShowOtherCountLimitContainer will only be passed in ValueContainer if it has a valid value. ie. greater than 0 */

    const updatedComponents = showOtherCountLimit > 0 ? {
        Option: CheckboxOption,
        ValueContainer: ShowOtherCountLimitContainer
    } : { Option: CheckboxOption };

    const addonProps = dropdownCheckbox ? {
        components: updatedComponents,
        closeMenuOnSelect: false,
        hideSelectedOptions: false
    } : {};

    const classNames = cn("clr-form-control", "rs-wrapper", {"clr-error": showError});
    return (
        <div className={ classNames } key={name}>
            {label && <BasicLabel label = {label} required = {required}
                helpTextPosition = {helpTextPosition} helpText = {helpText}  />}
            <div className={`react-select-box ${className}`}>
                <Select
                    {...defaultSelectProps}
                    {...addonProps}
                    // menuIsOpen={menuIsOpen}
                />
                {
                    showError &&
                    <span className="clr-subtext multiselect-error">
                        You can select upto {maxItems} items only.
                    </span>
                }
            </div>

        </div>

    );
};

ReactSelect.propTypes = {
    selectWithoutBox: PropTypes.bool
};

ReactSelect.defaultProps = {
    selectWithoutBox: false
};
export default ReactSelect;
```

Here, the `get` and `IsEmpty` methods are helper functions. `get` method gets the required value from any object or array and if the value is undefined, it assigns a default value there.
IsEmpty method checks whether passed value is empty array/object.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `onMenuOpen` and `onMenuClose` props in react select component
Create a state with boolean value and toggle the value based on menu open and menu close

https://react-select.com/props

A simple demo
https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-jepsen-7epx7u?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I know I need to use these props. But I don't know how will I access these props for displaying the button. Can you please provide some code snippet for it?

Comment: Sure let me update my answer

Comment: I have added a sandbox example
check it